# What is wrong with this c# method?

Tags: c#, methods, return-value, switch-statement

I use this method to get file extension,

```
public string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
    {
        switch (fileExtension)
        {
            case ".doc":
            case ".docx":
                return "application/ms-word";
        }
    }
```

When i compile it i got the error `BaseClass.ReturnExtension(string)': not all code paths return a value`.. Any suggestion...

Comment: You should not be case-sensitive.

Comment: ReturnExtension -> GetMimeTypeFromExtension :-)

Comment: As @Slaks says, if you're not forcing your argument to be lower-case before passing it to ReturnExtension(), then you probably want: switch (fileExtension.ToLower())

Comment: @JeffH: `ToLowerInvariant()`.

Comment: @Slaks - Updated my answer with your comment.

Comment: Why are you returning a MIME type from a method that is called ReturnExtension anyway? Rename your method so it reflects what it is doing.

Comment: @Slaks - Nice catch re "Invariant".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add a `default` condition if you are returning from inside the `switch` statement.

```
// As SLaks mentioned, you should be case in-sensitive.
// Therefore, I'm comparing only the Lower Case version of the extensio

switch(fileExtension.ToLowerInvariant())
{
    case ".doc":
    case ".docx":
        return "application/ms-word";
    default:
        // You could also throw an Exception here if unknown extensions
        // are truly invalid (which seems to be the more popular choice)
        //
        // Since it looks like you're returning a content-type for a
        // download, I would default to octet-stream so the user would
        // just get a download window.
        return "application/octet-stream";
}
```

Comment: @Adrian: Wrong. An empy case can implicitly fall through.

Answer (score 17):

You haven't specified what the method should return if fileExtension is not ".doc" or ".docx". You can do this by adding a default case to the switch statement. Assuming that other fileExtension values are invalid, you should throw an exception:

```
public string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".doc":
        case ".docx":
            return "application/ms-word";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid fileExtension '{0}'.", fileExtension));
    }
}
```

Comment: exception is better than silent default +1

Answer (score 4):

You need a default or you need to return something outside the `switch`.

```
default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        return "";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the better error messages a compiler can issue. It means exactly that: Not all code paths return a value.

A code path is created by branching statements like `while`, `if` and `switch`.

The compiler is trying to guarantee, that whenever the runtime executes this function, a value will be returned of the specified type (here: `string`).

In your example, the return value for a `fileextension` not in the set `(doc, docx)` is not defined. You can either

- specify a `default` clause in your `switch` statement
- or add a *catch-all* return statement at the end of your method (`return "text/plain"`?)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler derives a [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) from our source and sees that not all paths are covered, for example if you pass in a fileExtension ".rtf" this function can not provide a return value.

So either provide a return "something", at the end of the function or simply throw an exception for the switch's "default:" case. You have to decide about what the function needs to do in the cases when it neither sees a ".doc" or ".docx".

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself what happens when fileExtension is `.xls`. You have to return something in the default-case or simply after the switch statement:

```
public string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".doc":
        case ".docx":
            return "application/ms-word";
    }
    return "unknown";  // this path wasn't returning anything
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `default` and `break`, or a `break` on your last case statement.

Comment: No. There is no need for a break after a return.

Answer (score 0):

Just my $0.10, it's pretty clear that the content header is being returned here, so if we don't recognize the file extension, rather than throw exceptions or invalid MIME header information (e.g., "unknown"), we should return the file to the browser as an octect stream, like this:

```
public string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".doc":
        case ".docx":
            return "application/ms-word";
        default:
            return "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

This way we can accommodate scenarios where 5 years down the road, M$ releases MS-Word v30.1, and the extension becomes ".docz", the system will not throw exceptions, but invoke MS-Word (more) gracefully, albeit not using the IE-enhanced behavior that "application/ms-word" will.